# Oracle Extract the Day Name of the Week

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data that looks like this in a table called `Table_1`:

```
my_current_date_value
20-MAR-22
20-MAR-31
20-APR-29
```

What I want is this:

```
Wednesday
Friday
Saturday
```

How can I go about doing this in Oracle? I tried playing with the `TO_CHAR` function, but it does not like my current `'YY-MMM-DD'` format and I was unable to convert it to `'YYYY-MM-DD'` format.

**Here is what I tried using:**

SELECT TO_CHAR(DATE my_current_date_value, 'DAY')
FROM DUAL;

This seems to only work if I hard-code a single date, but not for a column full of dates. Any suggestions? This is what I mean when I say my code is not working.

Comment: Can you share the code you have tried and issue you are facing with that?

Comment: Done, I edited my post to include it.

Comment: Is the type of `my_current_date_value` column is DATE or String? What do you mean by `not working`?

Comment: `SELECT TO_CHAR(DATE '2023-APR-03', 'Day') AS "Day" from dual` - I think your current string returns a not valid date type, is that correct? Possible to throw schema for your table and oracle version?

Comment: It works when I use a single value, but I want it to work on a column of dates @bonCodigo.

Comment: `SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(my_current_date_value, 'YYYY-MON-DD'), 'DAY') FROM DUAL` Did you try this?

Comment: I tried a version of that, but I think I messed up when I was testing and made it more complicated than I needed to. Your solution works fine. I could not find any examples using a column anywhere, can you post your response as the answer to help future people who Google a solution? I'll mark it in 10 minutes.

Comment: The format mask for abbreviated month name is `MON`, not `MMM`. But the whole question depends on the datatype of `my_current_date_value`. Is it `DATE` or `VARCHAR2`?

Comment: The datatype of "my_current_date_value" is DATE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-- column 3 to reproduce your column date format
-- column 4 to retrieve desired Day format from it
-- so TO_CHAR(YOUR_DATE) should work, check your schema

SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'Day'), TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON'), TO_CHAR
    (SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY'), TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR
    (SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY')), 'Day') 
  from dual;
```

See if this work for you! (I'll put a better pic/table output later)
[image: result]

Answer (score 2):

You don't identify what the data type is so here are some variants to cover DATE/TIMESAMP (query 1) or VARCHAR2 (query 2):

```
SELECT mydate, TO_CHAR(mydate, 'fmDay') AS day 
FROM mytable;
```

| MYDATE | DAY |
| --- | --- |
| 20-MAR-22 | Sunday |
| 20-MAR-31 | Thursday |
| 20-APR-29 | Friday |

```
-- Now, assume the data is held as string (but I do hope this isn't true
SELECT mydate, TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(mydate, 'DD-MON-RR'), 'fmDay') AS day 
FROM mytable2;
```

| MYDATE | DAY |
| --- | --- |
| 20-MAR-22 | Sunday |
| 20-MAR-31 | Thursday |
| 20-APR-29 | Friday |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ir-X0Ws6)

btw: `TO_CHAR(...,'Day')` returns the day of the week with trailing spaces to match the longest possible day name. e.g. instead of "SUNDAY" you would get "SUNDAY ". Using “fm” (i.e. using `fmDay`) removes those trailing spaces.